# main thread was blocked when i use UIWebView

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiwebview, pthreads

Today i find a bug in my app relate to UIWebView, there are two case for it, the url i request is `https://estore-cn.pandora.net/Bracelets-1/`

When I use UIWebView to show a web page, and I exit that page, the webView's dealloc been called, but the UI thread been blocked, and several minutes later it recovers.

This is the thread stack here when I press  `pause program execution` button in Xcode.

`` * thread #1: tid = 0x580710, 0x0000000180da3f6c libsystem_kernel.dylib`__psynch_mutexwait + 8, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = signal SIGSTOP
  * frame #0: 0x0000000180da3f6c libsystem_kernel.dylib`__psynch_mutexwait + 8
    frame #1: 0x0000000180e7239c libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_mutex_lock_wait + 96
    frame #2: 0x0000000180e7257c libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_mutex_lock_slow + 296
    frame #3: 0x00000001850dc3b0 WebCore`_WebTryThreadLock(bool) + 52
    frame #4: 0x00000001850dcb3c WebCore`WebThreadLock + 108
    frame #5: 0x00000001865abfc0 UIKit`-[UIWebView dealloc] + 36
    frame #6: 0x000000010032ba64 QDaily`-[QDWebView dealloc](self=0x00000001575f3980, _cmd="dealloc") + 148 at QDWebView.m:63
    frame #7: 0x0000000180889ae8 libobjc.A.dylib`(anonymous namespace)::AutoreleasePoolPage::pop(void*) + 508
    frame #8: 0x00000001810e89fc CoreFoundation`_CFAutoreleasePoolPop + 28
    frame #9: 0x00000001811bebc0 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 1636
    frame #10: 0x00000001810e8c50 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 384
    frame #11: 0x00000001829d0088 GraphicsServices`GSEventRunModal + 180
    frame #12: 0x00000001863d6088 UIKit`UIApplicationMain + 204
    frame #13: 0x000000010037490c QDaily`main(argc=1, argv=0x000000016fd03af0) + 172 at main.m:16
    frame #14: 0x0000000180c868b8 libdyld.dylib`start + 4 ``

- second case is ,when i begin skip into the webView page, the same case happened.

`` thread #1: tid = 0x5801dc, 0x0000000180da3f6c libsystem_kernel.dylib`__psynch_mutexwait + 8, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = signal SIGSTOP
   frame #0: 0x0000000180da3f6c libsystem_kernel.dylib`__psynch_mutexwait + 8
    frame #1: 0x0000000180e7239c libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_mutex_lock_wait + 96
    frame #2: 0x0000000180e7257c libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_mutex_lock_slow + 296
    frame #3: 0x00000001850dc3b0 WebCore`_WebTryThreadLock(bool) + 52
    frame #4: 0x00000001850dcb3c WebCore`WebThreadLock + 108
    frame #5: 0x00000001867f3dc4 UIKit`-[UIWebView _webViewCommonInitWithWebView:scalesPageToFit:] + 128
    frame #6: 0x00000001865a83ec UIKit`-[UIWebView initWithFrame:] + 80
    frame #7: 0x00000001002abb60 QDaily`-[QDWebView initWithFrame:](self=0x0000000000000000, _cmd="initWithFrame:", frame=(origin = (x = 0, y = 20), size = (width = 414, height = 666))) + 120 at QDWebView.m:71
    frame #8: 0x0000000100212244 QDaily`-[QDSimpleWebViewController viewDidLoad](self=0x0000000131225070, _cmd="viewDidLoad") + 796 at QDSimpleWebViewController.m:57
    frame #9: 0x000000018636cc40 UIKit`-[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 996
    frame #10: 0x00000001863850d0 UIKit`-[UIViewController __viewWillAppear:] + 132
    frame #11: 0x000000018651fe5c UIKit`-[UINavigationController _startCustomTransition:] + 1052
    frame #12: 0x000000018642be40 UIKit`-[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded:] + 688
    frame #13: 0x000000018642bb1c UIKit`-[UINavigationController __viewWillLayoutSubviews] + 60
    frame #14: 0x000000018642ba84 UIKit`-[UILayoutContainerView layoutSubviews] + 208
    frame #15: 0x00000001863681e4 UIKit`-[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 656
    frame #16: 0x0000000183cf698c QuartzCore`-[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 148
    frame #17: 0x0000000183cf15c8 QuartzCore`CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 292
    frame #18: 0x0000000183cf1488 QuartzCore`CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 32
    frame #19: 0x0000000183cf0ab8 QuartzCore`CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*) + 252
    frame #20: 0x0000000183cf0818 QuartzCore`CA::Transaction::commit() + 500
    frame #21: 0x000000018636aff4 UIKit`_UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 4980
    frame #22: 0x00000001811c109c CoreFoundation`__CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 24
    frame #23: 0x00000001811c0b30 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 540
    frame #24: 0x00000001811be830 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 724
    frame #25: 0x00000001810e8c50 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 384
    frame #26: 0x00000001829d0088 GraphicsServices`GSEventRunModal + 180
    frame #27: 0x00000001863d6088 UIKit`UIApplicationMain + 204
    frame #28: 0x00000001002f490c QDaily`main(argc=1, argv=0x000000016fd83af0) + 172 at main.m:16
    frame #29: 0x0000000180c868b8 libdyld.dylib`start + 4 ``

I don't know how to resolve it

ADD: this is the webThread when happened dead lock

`` * thread #19: tid = 0x58076c, 0x00000001854180f0 WebCore`WTF::HashMap<unsigned long, WTF::RefPtr<WebCore::ResourceLoader>, WTF::IntHash<unsigned long>, WTF::HashTraits<unsigned long>, WTF::HashTraits<WTF::RefPtr<WebCore::ResourceLoader> > >::remove(unsigned long const&) + 164, name = 'WebThread'
  * frame #0: 0x00000001854180f0 WebCore`WTF::HashMap<unsigned long, WTF::RefPtr<WebCore::ResourceLoader>, WTF::IntHash<unsigned long>, WTF::HashTraits<unsigned long>, WTF::HashTraits<WTF::RefPtr<WebCore::ResourceLoader> > >::remove(unsigned long const&) + 164
    frame #1: 0x0000000185126e54 WebCore`WebCore::DocumentLoader::removeSubresourceLoader(WebCore::ResourceLoader*) + 40
    frame #2: 0x00000001851292a0 WebCore`WebCore::ResourceLoader::cancel(WebCore::ResourceError const&) + 492
    frame #3: 0x0000000185087764 WebCore`WebCore::ResourceLoader::init(WebCore::ResourceRequest const&) + 404
    frame #4: 0x00000001850873fc WebCore`WebCore::SubresourceLoader::startLoading() + 36
    frame #5: 0x000000018508735c WebCore`WebCore::ResourceLoadScheduler::servePendingRequests(WebCore::ResourceLoadScheduler::HostInformation*, WebCore::ResourceLoadPriority) + 516
    frame #6: 0x00000001851070b8 WebCore`WebCore::ResourceLoadScheduler::servePendingRequests(WebCore::ResourceLoadPriority) + 412
    frame #7: 0x0000000185079f1c WebCore`WebCore::ThreadTimers::sharedTimerFiredInternal() + 148
    frame #8: 0x0000000185079e5c WebCore`WebCore::timerFired(__CFRunLoopTimer*, void*) + 36
    frame #9: 0x00000001811c1794 CoreFoundation`__CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 28
    frame #10: 0x00000001811c1438 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopDoTimer + 884
    frame #11: 0x00000001811beb4c CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 1520
    frame #12: 0x00000001810e8c50 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 384
    frame #13: 0x00000001850da108 WebCore`RunWebThread(void*) + 456
    frame #14: 0x0000000180e6fb28 libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_body + 156
    frame #15: 0x0000000180e6fa8c libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_start + 156
    frame #16: 0x0000000180e6d028 libsystem_pthread.dylib`thread_start + 4 ``

ADD: JavaScriptCore :: Marking thread
`` * thread #20: tid = 0x58076d, 0x0000000180da3f24 libsystem_kernel.dylib`__psynch_cvwait + 8, name = 'JavaScriptCore::Marking'
  * frame #0: 0x0000000180da3f24 libsystem_kernel.dylib`__psynch_cvwait + 8
    frame #1: 0x0000000180e6ece8 libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_cond_wait + 648
    frame #2: 0x00000001807fb42c libc++.1.dylib`std::__1::condition_variable::wait(std::__1::unique_lock<std::__1::mutex>&) + 56
    frame #3: 0x0000000184bc0d5c JavaScriptCore`JSC::GCThread::waitForNextPhase() + 144
    frame #4: 0x0000000184bc0df4 JavaScriptCore`JSC::GCThread::gcThreadMain() + 84
    frame #5: 0x0000000184896614 JavaScriptCore`WTF::threadEntryPoint(void*) + 212
    frame #6: 0x0000000184896524 JavaScriptCore`WTF::wtfThreadEntryPoint(void*) + 24
    frame #7: 0x0000000180e6fb28 libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_body + 156
    frame #8: 0x0000000180e6fa8c libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_start + 156
    frame #9: 0x0000000180e6d028 libsystem_pthread.dylib`thread_start + 4 ``

Comment: please update the question with your code to replicate the issue.

Comment: please provide ur code ...it will useful to resolve the issue with ur error code

Comment: just for this url will dead lock, other is naturally.

Comment: u said ur exiting the webpage how u r .. exiting ?

Comment: @NAVEENKUMAR It's a webView controller ,i just pop it.